# draw rectangles with common edge

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to following picture in tikz, for which I have written the code.
However scaling this image, distorts the location of the rectangle nodes. In my picture shown, there are common edges between the nodes. Irrespective of scaling, I don't want them to be distorted. Could someone give me tips to resolve this problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (rxst0) at (0.75,-0.5) [draw,fill=gray!20,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=0.5cm] {$st_0$};
    \node (rxst1) at (2.25,-0.5) [draw,fill=gray!20,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=0.5cm] {$st_1$};

    \node (c0pos0) at (0,0) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1.0cm] {$pos_0$};
    \node (c0st0) at (0.75,0) [draw,fill=gray,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=0.5cm] {$st_0$};
    \node (c0pos1)  at (1.55,0) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1.0cm] {$pos_1$};
    \node (c0st1) at (2.25,0) [draw,fill=gray,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=0.5cm] {$st_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is how the distorted image looks like -

[image]

I also tried something like following, but it doesn't work.

`\node (c0st0) [anchor=west,right of=c0pos0,node distance=0cm,draw,fill=gray,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=0.5cm] {$st_0$};`

Thank You

Comment: Use `positioning` tikzlibrary

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure of understanding what do you mean with "scale". The following figure and code are inmune to scaling, because positions are specified relative to other nodes, and widths and heights are specified in absolute units:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  mybox/.style = {
     minimum width=#1, 
     minimum height=0.65cm, 
     inner sep=3pt, 
     draw},
  mybox/.default=0.5cm,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth]
\node [mybox=1cm, fill=white] (c0pos0) {$pos_0$};
\node [mybox,fill=gray,right=of c0pos0] (rxst0) {$st_0$};
\node [mybox,fill=gray!20,below=of rxst0] {$st_0$};
\node [mybox=1cm,fill=white,right=of rxst0] (c0pos1) {$pos_1$};
\node [mybox,fill=gray,right=of c0pos1] (rxst1) {$st_1$};
\node [mybox,fill=gray!20,below=of rxst1] {$st_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth, scale=2]
\node [mybox=1cm, fill=white] (c0pos0) {$pos_0$};
\node [mybox,fill=gray,right=of c0pos0] (rxst0) {$st_0$};
\node [mybox,fill=gray!20,below=of rxst0] {$st_0$};
\node [mybox=1cm,fill=white,right=of rxst0] (c0pos1) {$pos_1$};
\node [mybox,fill=gray,right=of c0pos1] (rxst1) {$st_1$};
\node [mybox,fill=gray!20,below=of rxst1] {$st_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

## Update

Following suggestions by @Ignasi (which I agree with), this is an alternative definition of `mybox` style:

```
\tikzset{
  mybox/.style = {
     text width=#1, 
     text centered,
     text height=4mm, 
     text depth=2.5mm,
     inner sep=3pt, 
     draw},
  mybox/.default=0.5cm,
}
```

Which, using the same `tikzpicture` code than above, produces:

[image: Result2]

Comment: I think what I was doing wrong was not including `node distance=-\pgflinewidth`. This is something I learned new. Thanks for the answer! Its perfectly what I was looking for.

Comment: I think some `text height` and `text depth` will help to better align nodes text.

Answer (score 5):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text
\usepackage{multido}  % for \multido
\usepackage{pstricks} % for the rest of the drawing

\begin{document}

\def\blocks{2} % the number of different indices
\begin{pspicture}(\numexpr 5*\blocks,4)
\psset{dimen = middle, fillstyle = solid} % `dimen = middle` gives you perfectly overlapping rectangles as wanted
  \multido{\iA = 0+5, \iB = 0+1}{\blocks}{%
    \psframe(\iA,2)(!\iA\space 3 add 4)
    \rput(!\iA\space 1.5 add 3){\Huge $\text{pos}_{\iB}$}
    \psframe[fillcolor = black!60](!\iA\space 3 add 2)(!\iA\space 5 add 4)
    \rput(!\iA\space 4 add 3){\Huge $\text{st}_{\iB}$}
    \psframe[fillcolor = black!20](!\iA\space 3 add 0)(!\iA\space 5 add 2)
    \rput(!\iA\space 4 add 1){\Huge $\text{st}_{\iB}$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]